# Symfony 2 - Entity have no fields %name%

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hello i'm trying to select row by title

Entity\Pages.php

```
<?php
namespace Dproc\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("fn")
 *
 */
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="pages")
 */
class Pages
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $page_title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $page_content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $page_category;

    /**
     * Get Id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }

    /**
     * Set page_title
     *
     * @param string $pageTitle
     * @return Pages
     */
    public function setPageTitle($pageTitle)
    {
        $this->page_title = $pageTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page_title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageTitle()
    {
        return $this->page_title;
    }

    /**
     * Set page_content
     *
     * @param string $pageContent
     * @return Pages
     */
    public function setPageContent($pageContent)
    {
        $this->page_content = $pageContent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page_content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageContent()
    {
        return $this->page_content;
    }

    /**
     * Set page_category
     *
     * @param string $pageCategory
     * @return Pages
     */
    public function setPageCategory($pageCategory)
    {
        $this->page_category = $pageCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page_category
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageCategory()
    {
        return $this->page_category;
    }
}
```

CourseController

```
<?php

namespace Dproc\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Dproc\MainBundle\Entity\Pages;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function IndexAction($slug)
    {
        $page = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('DprocMainBundle:Pages')
           ->findByPageTitle($slug);

        if (!$page) {
           throw $this->createNotFoundException('No product found for slug '.$slug);
        }
        return $this->render('DprocMainBundle:Dproc:single.html.twig',array('page' => $page));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find it by page_title so i tried findByPageTitle($slug) but it shows

```
Entity 'Dproc\MainBundle\Entity\Pages' has no field 'pageTitle'. You can therefore not call 'findByPageTitle' on the entities' repository
```

What i'm doing wrong, and how can i select row by page_title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony's coding standards specify that you need to use camelcase syntax on your variables.

My guess is that you used the underscore syntax because you wanted your columns in your database to have underscores.

You can specify a column name by using the attribute `name` to the `Column` annotation.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_title", type="text")
 */
protected $pageTitle;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_content", type="text")
 */
protected $pageContent;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_category", type="text")
 */
protected $pageCategory;
```

I'd highly advise you to read the [coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) so you don't get stuck in this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: Yes that worked, I have one question, you wrote name="page_category" and soo.. That name must be same as table column name right?

Comment: Yes, `name="page_category"` is the name of the column in the database table. Think of the ORM annotations as way to interact with the database and the code. Your *own* PHP code will not use values in the ORM tags but will use the PHP variables and Doctrine ORM layer will translate that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet in you entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_title", type="text")
 */
protected $pageTitle;
```

Don't forget to modity the get and set for the field.

Try and stick to the Symfony2 standards: http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html

Comment: Okay thanks, but what if my variable is not pageTitle but page_title, how i can do in that case(i'll do like u said for sure, but how it will work in this case)

Comment: then your only option is to use findBy(array('page_title' => $slug));